# How to add user input to array list

Tags: vb.net, winforms

the program is supposed to take the text in from the text boxes, combine it into a NewCustomer element, and then display it in a listbox. Below is the code i'm supposed to add to, i've tried lstCustomer.add(txtFirstname.text) but it turned to be an error. Thanks in advance for helping.

```
Public Class Form1

Private myCustomers As New ArrayList

Public ReadOnly Property SelectedCustomer As Customer
    Get
        Dim index As Integer = lstCustomer.SelectedIndex
        If index <> -1 Then
            Return lstCustomer.Items(index)

        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Get
End Property


Public Sub NewCustomer(ByVal fn As String, ByVal ln As String, ByVal a As Integer, ByVal e As String)

    Dim temp As Customer
    temp.FirstName = fn
    temp.LastName = ln
    temp.Age = a
    temp.Email = e

    myCustomers.Add(temp)

    Me.lstCustomer.Items.Add(temp)
End Sub

Private Sub BtnTest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnTest.Click

    NewCustomer("Homer", "Simpson", 40, "HSimpson@springf.com")
    NewCustomer("Bruce", "Banner", 44, "green@giant.com")

End Sub


Public Sub displayCustomer(ByVal temp As Customer)
    Me.TxtName.Text = temp.name
    Me.TxtFirstName.Text = temp.FirstName
    Me.TxtLastName.Text = temp.LastName
    Me.TxtAge.Text = temp.Age
    Me.TxtEmail.Text = temp.Email
End Sub


Private Sub BtnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnAdd.Click
    lstCustomer.add(TxtFirstName.Text And TxtLastName.Text And TxtEmail.Text And TxtAge.Text)



End Sub
```

Comment: This is not C#, this is VB

Comment: It isn't VBA either. Please, explain: "it turned to be an error". Which error?

Comment: The ArrayList became redundant about 20 years ago: it would be better to use `Private myCustomers As New List(Of Customer)`.

Comment: There are some points you’ve added a string value to the the list box, other points your adding an instance of a customer class

Comment: `lstCustomer.add(TxtFirstName.Text And TxtLastName.Text And TxtEmail.Text And TxtAge.Text)` should be `lstCustomer.add(TxtFirstName.Text, TxtLastName.Text, CInt(TxtAge.Text), TxtEmail.Text)`. You need to separate the parameters with commas, not the `And` operator, and you need to supply them in the correct order as shown in the method declaration.

Comment: If you set [Option Strict On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) for this project and make it the default for new projects, then Visual Studio will be able to point out problems like that for you.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using data binding, this makes it easier to work with the ListBox. First make sure to override `ToString` in the `Customer` class to make is displayable in the ListBox

```vb
Public Class Customer
    Public Property FirstName As String
    Public Property LastName As String
    Public Property Age As Integer
    Public Property Email As String

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return $"{FirstName} {LastName} ({Age}) {Email}"
    End Function
End Class
```

Then we use a `List(Of Customer)` instead of an `ArrayList`. The advantage is that the `List(Of )` is strongly typed, i.e., its elements are of type `Customer`, where as the `ArrayList` has elements of type `Object`.

Also, we create a wrapper of type `BindingList(Of Customer)` to wrap our list to enable auto-updating of the ListBox. Example:

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Dim customers As New List(Of Customer)
    Dim customersBinding As BindingList(Of Customer)

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()

        customersBinding = New BindingList(Of Customer)(customers)
        lstCustomer.DataSource = customersBinding
    End Sub

    Private Sub NewCustomer(ByVal fn As String, ByVal ln As String, ByVal a As Integer, ByVal e As String)
        Dim customer As New Customer With {
            .FirstName = fn,
            .LastName = ln,
            .Age = a,
            .Email = e
        }
        customersBinding.Add(customer)
        lstCustomer.SelectedItem = customers(customers.Count - 1)
        ' or    lstCustomer.SelectedIndex = customers.Count - 1
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnTest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnTest.Click
        NewCustomer("Homer", "Simpson", 40, "HSimpson@springf.com")
        NewCustomer("Bruce", "Banner", 44, "green@giant.com")
    End Sub

    Public Sub DisplayCustomer(ByVal customer As Customer)
        TxtFirstName.Text = customer.FirstName
        TxtLastName.Text = customer.LastName
        TxtAge.Text = customer.Age.ToString()
        TxtEmail.Text = customer.Email
    End Sub

    Private Sub lstCustomer_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstCustomer.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim index As Integer = lstCustomer.SelectedIndex
        If index >= 0 Then
            DisplayCustomer(customers(index))
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        NewCustomer(TxtFirstName.Text, TxtLastName.Text, CInt(TxtAge.Text), TxtEmail.Text)
    End Sub
End Class
```

In the constructor we create the binding list and set it as data source of the ListBox.

See how `Sub NewCustomer` only adds the new customer to the binding list. This inserts the customer to the wrapped list as well and at the same time updates the ListBox.

We also automatically select the last inserted customer in the ListBox with

```vb
lstCustomer.SelectedItem = customers(customers.Count - 1)
```

or (easier)

```vb
lstCustomer.SelectedIndex = customers.Count - 1
```

We use the `SelectedIndexChanged` event to automatically display the customer in the textboxes when the user selects another customer in the listbox.

You could also extend data binding to automatically bind the customer objects to the textboxes. You will find a lot of online tutorials on this subject.